# Are the Crab God and other supernatural creatures metaphors?

Tags: monogatari-series

I'm new to the *Monogatari* series; got into it because Nisio Isin wrote *Medaka Box* and also GIFs I found online.

I just don't understand whether we are intended to take the supernatural parts of the show to understand the characters or whether they are important on their own yet. For example, in the LNs, does the monologue hint at what is reality and what is made up?

How much of the content in the show can be chalked up to hallucination, etc.? Is the crab god really there? Or is it a metaphor for her not carrying her trauma, thus she is weightless? Or both?

Comment: The light novels and future episodes of the anime strongly indicate that all the supernatural stuff is literally real, not a hallucination or a metaphor. There are some interesting hints in the later stories about how the existence of the supernatural interacts with human thought and belief, but never an indication that the supernatural creatures don't exist.

Comment: @Torisuda you might post that as answer instead...